# Creating a new iOS mail client

Tags: ios, exchange-server, imap, pop3

Where do I get info on POP, IMAP, Exchange API connection info? I have the UI figured out; I just cannot find any information on connecting to POP, IMAP, Exchange APIs.

Comment: Please be clearer about what you're looking for. Libraries? Protocol specifications? And what have you looked at already?

Comment: I used to want to ask similar. I didn't know that "RFC" and "Protocol" were synonyms, and I asked how to find and interact with RFC's via sockets and was downvoted myself for that. I kinda wish more people would realize that not all of us went through structured learning and have the same foundational skills, you don't deserve the downvote

Answer (score 1):

POP, IMAP, Exchange, and SMTP are all internet protocols that talk to servers to access and send email. iOS doesn't natively expose any of this functionality directly. You'll either have to build it yourself, or find libraries that you can use which already do.

Implementing these yourself would be a *ton* of work. Google can direct you to plenty of information on POP and IMAP, which are open standard protocols.

POP spec: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1939

IMAP spec: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501

(Neither of these cover secure TLS, or other modern and critical extensions.) You're best off finding a library that speaks these protocols to use in your app.

You'll also need SMTP for outbound mail-- the POP and IMAP specs cover accessing a mailbox, but not sending email.

Exchange uses MAPI/RPC, which is a proprietary standard that Microsoft owns and maintains.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messaging_Application_Programming_Interface
It is unlikely you'll be able to use this protocol without a license and probably code from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

POP and IMAP are Internet standards. You can find them documented in the relevant RFC's.

Exchange is obviously Microsoft's proprietary protocol, so the MS web site is probably the place to start.

Answer (score 0):

MailCore is a Mac and iOS library designed to ease the pain of working with e-mail protocols. MailCore is batteries included with support for SMTP, IMAP, POP3, RFC822, MIME and rendering of HTML messages.

http://libmailcore.com/